# Telerik OpenAccess ORM with SQL Server 2005

Tags: c#, telerik-mvc, telerik-open-access

I'm trying out this ORM & new to this. I have following code:

```
IObjectScope scope = Database.Get("MyConnection").GetObjectScope();

try
{
   scope.Transaction.Begin();
   Reading r = new Reading();
   r.ReadingURL = reading.ReadingURL;
   r.IsActive = true;
   scope.Add(r);
   scope.Transaction.Commit();
}
finally
{
   scope.Dispose();
}
```

When I run this I get following error on "Add":

> *Telerik.OpenAccess.Exceptions.InvalidOperationException: Class
>   'WritingChallenge.Reading' is persistent but not known in this
>   context.*

It seems for some reason database connection is lost? I'm not sure what is the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the model that was connected to the `WritingReplacementConnection` was having no information about the `WritingChallenge`.Reading type.

Did you specify a `mappingConfiguration` that included this type?

You can also ask this kind of questions in the forums at [Telerik Forums - .NET ORM](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/orm.aspx).

Comment: could you please put some light on "mappingConfiguration". My telerik generated classes are not part of model but my model class is extended to Telerik class. I went with this approach so I can have clear separation between the two in case there is database update in the future. This won't effect my custom methods

Comment: For your information: the provided link seems to be dead.